# YouTube: Is there a way I can get the list of videos viewed by the user?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to build a video recommender for the user of my Android application. I have Google OAuth to login in my app. Can I get the data about the videos viewed by the user of my app on YouTube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a two-step process with the v3 API:

**1.** Hit [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) method with an OAuth2 request of the logged in user.  Pass in `contentDetails` for the `part` value and `mine` = `true`.

Request:

```
HTTP GET: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"xmg9xJZuZD438sF4hb-VcBBREXc/41Jk5t11dHi2JfUXrF4jZJhaQnE\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"xmg9xJZuZD438sF4hb-VcBBREXc/wfaiZMzCHBlyq_ZFJU5pMR4q4sg\"",
   "id": "UCt7iVnJwjBsof8IPLJHCTgQ",
   "contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
     "likes": "LLt7iVnJwjBsof8IPLJHCTgQ",
     "favorites": "FLt7iVnJwjBsof8IPLJHCTgQ",
     "uploads": "UUt7iVnJwjBsof8IPLJHCTgQ",
     "watchHistory": "HLt7iVnJwjBsof8IPLJHCTgQ",
     "watchLater": "WLt7iVnJwjBsof8IPLJHCTgQ"
    },
    "googlePlusUserId": "103927393533363914063"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

The object for the `watchHistory` key is the `playlistId` of your viewing history.  Keep this value for use in step 2.

**2.** Hit the [`playlistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) method with the `watchHistory` `playlistId` from step 1.

Request:

```
HTTP GET: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&id=HLt7iVnJwjBsof8IPLJHCTgQ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"xmg9xJZuZD438sF4hb-VcBBREXc/ozXLhcdE2ZWgvJu3ywqxtfQeL7o\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

The contents of the `items` array will have your viewing history.

Please note that there is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4642) with the v3 API where your history will not be returned.  This has been reported internally to YouTube's team and was supposed to be fixed two years ago.